# Nftables DNAT doesn't seem to be working

Tags: networking, centos, nat, nftables

I am trying to setup a DNAT on my new centos 8 using nftables. This utility (and centos 8) is new to me, I've been using iptables (centos through 6) for ages.

My assumption is that I did not setup something properly for DNAT to kick in, however I may just not be using the tools properly. Or both.

Anyhow, in case it matters, here's a previous question of mine on some routing issues on the same box: [Multiple internet connections, incoming packets on wrong NIC port (inbound routing issue?)](https://superuser.com/q/1521996/70234) (problem was an ARP flux, solved).

Here's below a sketch of my current setup and blue line marks what I want to happen (the expected "path")

[image]

Basically, packets come in from the internet, go over interface 2 (ens2), are DNATed thru the local interface (ens5, local IP 192.168.1.10) to 192.168.1.2.
(Once this is working, the same will be setup for ens 3 and 4, going to a couple of different VMs on the same LAN)

I have verified that packets come in on the correct interface (the expected nft log triggers), however,  `conntrack -E` does not show anything.

Also, the iptables logging on the centos 6 box (the actual target, 192.168.1.2) does not show anything (the same logging put in place ages ago was showing expected output the last time I checked, a few months ago, so that box should in theory be ok)

Here's my nftables script as-is right now, with IP's/IF's translated to match sketch.

```
table ip nat {
    chain PREROUTING {
            type nat hook prerouting priority -100; policy accept;
            iif "ens2" goto PREROUTING_RDS2
            iif "ens3" goto PREROUTING_RDS3
    }

    chain PREROUTING_RDS2 {
            tcp dport { http, https } log prefix "RDS2_dnat-3 "
            tcp dport { http, https } dnat to IP_6
    }

    chain PREROUTING_RDS3 {
            tcp dport { http, https } log prefix "RDS3_dnat-3 "
            tcp dport { http, https } dnat to IP_6
    }
}

table inet filter {
    chain INPUT {
            type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
            #
            iif "lo" accept
            #
            # allow ping
            ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request limit rate 1/second log prefix "PING "
            ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request limit rate 1/second accept
            # following is required and must be BEFORE the ct state established otherwise the ping flooding will not be stopped
            ip protocol icmp drop
            #
            ct state established,related accept
            ct status dnat accept
            #
            iifname "ens5" goto INPUT_LOCAL
            #
            # now we drop the rest
            ct state invalid log prefix "INPUT_STATE_INVALID_DROP: "
            ct state invalid drop
            log prefix "INPUT_FINAL_REJECT: "
            reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited
    }

    chain FILTER {
            type filter hook forward priority 50; policy drop;
            iif "ens2" goto FILTER_RDS2
            iif "ens3" goto FILTER_RDS3
    }

    chain INPUT_LOCAL {
            tcp dport ssh goto INPUT_LOCAL_ssh
    }

    chain INPUT_LOCAL_ssh {
            ip saddr IP_MY_PC accept
    }

    chain FILTER_RDS2 {
            oifname "ens5" ip daddr IP_6 tcp dport { http, https } accept
    }

    chain FILTER_RDS3 {
            oifname "ens5" ip daddr IP_6 tcp dport { http, https } accept
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would say your gateway on the LAN is incorrect for sure. It is 192.168.1.1 while it very likely should have been 192.168.1.10 - IP5 on ens5 on CentOS gateway.

Comment: Did you enable ip forwarding and what's the content and policy of your FORWARD chain?

Comment: Gateway IP is correct, my LAN currently has a different gateway going out through a  different ISP (also physically different)

Comment: If you go through different gateway from IP6 how do you want to restore the source address of the returning packet?

Comment: I have not explicitly enabled ip forwarding no. That is the entire nft script attached, so nothing in FORWARD. I assumed the default policy is accept. None of the sites I've read on the subject mentioned anything about forwarding so I assumed it's "default ok". see eg: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Performing_Network_Address_Translation_(NAT)

Comment: well so far the packet isn't reaching IP 6, but my assumption is that since internally it will come from .10 to .2, the netfilter conntrack on .2 should know that and return on .10 ... But that's just my assumption.

Comment: You have to enable ip forwarding for nftables exactly the same way as you did for iptables (by writing 1 to /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward directly or using sysctl).

Comment: btw, all PC's on LAN have same gateway. 192.168.1.1 (also a centos 6 box). I am just setting up a new GW, but until everything is working fine, I will keep my old one as actual gateway so I have my stuff functioning (in and out)

Comment: Your assumption about return path is incorrect. It will go to default gateway as the only source of the packet destination is the routing table.

Comment: I enabled forwarding, Still no game. However I was wrong, I named my forward chains "FILTER" by mistake. So I have a forward hook policy drop and an input interface filter, with an output interface filter on destination IP and port, with accept, Please refer to FILTER and FILTER_RDS2 in the original nft script attached to the Q for reference. Is that ok? Still not seeing any incoming packets on local IP .2

Comment: Regarding gateway, No way to have 2 gateway PCs on the same subnet, right? (google doesn't show me anything relevant on "multiple gateways" searches) I'll need to make a new LAN for this right? like 192.168.2.0/24 and have this box on ens5 have 192.168.1.2 and add a new ip for the other one in this subnet as well. Would that solve the DNAT issue too?

Comment: Your issues come from the routing tables added in the previous Q/A. Those routing tables are there because you use multiple interfaces in the same LAN, rather than multiple IPs on one interface. This makes everything else more complex including this question.I might give an answer, because I answered the previous, but if you don't understand perfectly how routing (and rules and routing tables and then netfilter and marks) is working, you will have trouble to manage additional changes in the future. you should consider having only ens1 without ens2/ens3/ens4, this would simplify your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this question is difficult to answer without taking a good look at the [previous Q/A](https://superuser.com/questions/1521996/multiple-internet-connections-incoming-packets-on-wrong-nic-port-inbound-routi) solving the initial setup for *centos8*. The solution becomes very complex. Considering the kind of configuration that must be put in place for this, it's probably not worth having one IP per interface, with multiple interfaces on the same LAN, rather than all IPs on the same interface, especially considering it's in a virtual environment: there won't be any speed-up. Any change to configuration, will have to be reflected all along the commands below, so managing this correctly will be difficult.

---

### *centos8* router

Since to solve the multiple-interfaces-in-same-LAN problem there are additional routing tables, now that in this Q/A *centos8* is acting as a router, more route entries must be duplicated from the main table to the additional routing tables:

```
# ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev ens5 table 1001 src 192.168.1.10 
# ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev ens5 table 1002 src 192.168.1.10 
# ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev ens5 table 1003 src 192.168.1.10 
# ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev ens5 table 1004 src 192.168.1.10
```

else any packet received on *ens1*, *ens2*, *ens3* or *ens4* and *dnat*ed through *ens5* will fail [reverse path filter](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v4.18#n1141) since there's no route through *ens5* on those tables.

Of course that's not enough: there is no information in the reply packets (eg: coming back from *centos6*) about what interface was used and should be reused the other way around. So this information has to be memorized per-flow, using netfilter's conntrack. In nftables rules, delete the whole `ip nat` table:

```
# nft delete table ip nat
```

and replace it with this new table `ip markandnat`:

```
# nft -f - << 'EOF'
table ip markandnat {
        map iif2mark {
                type iface_index : mark;
                elements = {
                        ens1 : 101,
                        ens2 : 102,
                        ens3 : 103,
                        ens4 : 104
                }
        }

        map mark2daddr {
                type mark : ipv4_addr;
                elements = {
                        102 : 192.168.1.2,
                        103 : 192.168.1.2, # same IP, as per OP's config
                        104 : 192.168.1.4  # some other VM
                }
        }
        chain premark {
                type filter hook prerouting priority -150; policy accept;
                meta mark set ct mark meta mark != 0 return
                meta mark set iif map @iif2mark meta mark != 0 ct mark set meta mark
        }

        chain prenat {
                type nat hook prerouting priority -100; policy accept;
                tcp dport { http, https } dnat to meta mark map @mark2daddr
        }
}
EOF
```

This will map interface => mark => dnat destination, while saving the mark as conntrack's mark (see the link at the end about *connmark* usage). Now this mark will be available and used by the routing stack by adding the rules below, to point to the same additional routing tables:

```
# ip rule add pref 11001 fwmark 101 table 1001
# ip rule add pref 11002 fwmark 102 table 1002
# ip rule add pref 11003 fwmark 103 table 1003
# ip rule add pref 11004 fwmark 104 table 1004
```

but there's still a missing part: again about reverse path filter. When marks are in use, reverse path filter isn't rechecking using the new routes altered by the marks and usually fails check. Actually there's an [undocumented feature, added in kernel 2.6.33/2.6.32.8 in 2009/2010](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v2.6.32.8&id=ecb7287c5f53747767efa0f0e844da69a6ec3a51), which happens to solve this problem, without the need to use loose reverse path mode: `src_valid_mark`.

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.ens1.src_valid_mark=1
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.ens2.src_valid_mark=1
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.ens3.src_valid_mark=1
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.ens4.src_valid_mark=1
```

---

### *centos6* server

If you want to use an alternate gateway temporarily, even if that's again adding complexity and probably unforeseen subtle side effects, it's possible, again by using marks. As it's CentOS 6, *nftables* is not available, so *iptables* will be used.

I'll consider that the *centos6* VM has IP 192.168.1.2/24 on (unique) interface *eth0*, and default gw 192.168.1.1. Let's add a new routing table and rule for the alternate gateway 192.168.1.10:

```
# ip route add table 10 default via 192.168.1.10
# ip rule add fwmark 10 lookup 10
```

Put the *iptables* rules (here only the *mangle* table is needed):

```
# iptables-restore << 'EOF'
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
-A PREROUTING -m mark ! --mark 0 -j RETURN
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 10
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 10
-A PREROUTING -m mark ! --mark 0 -j CONNMARK --save-mark
-A OUTPUT -m connmark ! --mark 0 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
COMMIT
EOF
```

Now any flow received on ports 80 or 443 will mark the incoming packets and their replies. This mark will be used by the routing stack to change the gateway to 192.168.1.10 for incoming and replies (*mangle/OUTPUT* triggers a reroute check, see 2nd link below).

It appears there's no need to use `src_valid_mark` in this case, but just set it or set `rp_filter=2` if it doesn't work. This setting won't allow also receiving *dnat*ed traffic through 192.168.1.1.

---

Some links:

- [To Linux and beyond ! Netfilter Connmark](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/netfilter-connmark/)
- [Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I took a bit of research along that, and it's indeed too nasty to maintain. I'll try to setup the stuff with all 3 IPs on 1 interface and see where that leads me, and if I can't manage to get it working, I will open a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from comments the most immediate and important omission is turned off ip forwarding. Just:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

and check if now the DNATted packets arrive to IP6.

The second issue is asymmetric routing. The DNATted packets come to IP6 through 192.168.1.10 (IP5) where they are modified (destination address is altered). The return packets will go through default gateway on the LAN (182.168.1.1) and they will not be modified on route to the connection origin. They will likely keep their RFC1918 address or will be SNATted to something different on 192.168.1.1 and will never match any connection on their destination and will likely be dropped.

EDIT:

So, to address FORWARD chain I would rewrite it to the following (much simpler IMHO):

```
table inet filter {
:
    chain FORWARD {
            type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
            ct state established,related accept
            ct status dnat accept
    }
:
}
```

Comment: As per comments earlier, enabling ip forward did not resolve this. The FILTER chains may be the cause? Second issue acknowledged. Will address it once DNAT to IP6 works, unless that's a prerequisite. Thanks

Comment: FORWARD, not FILTER. Just give it a try, I don't know for sure if you have to create it for forwarding to work. BTW, why not relay on state and status match (similar to what you have in INPUT chain) for FORWARD chain? It's simpler.

Comment: Spent a couple hours trying all sorts of things, no game (started with your edit, google results, and eventually I also tested with FORWARD policy accept, and an explicit accept in it (unconditional accept everything). Let's assume I'm checking/testing the DNAT wrong (or something is broken somewhere outside the gateway; maybe even on the gateway). Is there a reliable way to check the DNAT is successful on the gateway itself? If not, how about on the target? Thanks

Comment: @A.B I ran "   tcpdump -nn -i [name] > file  "  for all the public interfaces and the local one on CO8, and the only one on CO6. On CO8, greping the files for the local target IP shows nothing. Greping for the source outside IP shows results only on ens2 as expected: All results are of the form  
SIP.port > IP2.80: Flags [S], seq 1281218871, win 8192, options [mss 1420,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0  
SIP.port > IP2.80: Flags [S], seq 1281218871, win 8192, options [mss 1420,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0  
On the CO6 there is nothing related to either SIP, IP2 or IP5.

Comment: @A.B rp_filter is enabled and "nstat -rsz | grep IPReversePathFilter" shows it's incrementing while testing it. It actually makes sense since I setup the routing to have LAN-traffic on ens1, and internet-inbound (servers) on ens 2<->4. Setting rp_filter to 2 seems to allow it through, still not working though so moving on. Can you put that as an answer though?

Comment: I've set up a secondary LAN-2 (different subnet) using aliases on the LAN-1 interfaces. I can ping centos 6 TO centos 8. Not the other way around. Interestingly, I cannot ping CO8 to either LAN-1 or LAN-2. CO6 does not show any dropped packets during the failing centos8 ping. tcpdump on both CO6 and CO8 shows the ping requests and replies (both LANs). But ping command from CO8 says 100% packet loss. Any ideas what I may have forgotten in nft or maybe broken with these settings we've changed? CO8 doesn't log dropped packets so it's not an explicit drop.

Comment: Turns out it was an explicit drop for the ping (script is in Q body), I've fixed that and added logging for that drop. Rechecked the entire script for any other non-logged drops, policy or explicit, nothing found. So now ping works both ways. I'll continue investigating why other services don't work on LAN2, and once those work, hopefully the DNAT will work as well.